# How to control the contrast on videos using Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, electron

On the left side is my electron application with one youtube video. On the right side is my app created with pygtk2 and webkit. The contrast is better with webkit. With Electron, the black board arround the video diverges. How can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about Electron uses webm in chromium. The python webkit app uses mp4. Mp4 is not available in the Electron because it's a proprietary format. The solution that I found for control this difference about the contrast was in css filters on the video element.

```
-webkit-filter: contrast(120%);
```

Article about [css filters](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/)